# Week 1 Game Theory Example 7

Tags: game-theory

Example 7.
Verify that the strategies $y^{*}=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}),x^{*}=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4})$ are optimal and $v=0$ is the value of the game $\overline{\Gamma}_{A}$ with matrix
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&-1\\
-1&-1&3\\
-1&3&-1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Adding a unity to all elements of the matrix $A$, we get the matrix

$$A^{'}=
\begin{bmatrix}
2&0&0\\
0&0&4\\
0&4&0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Each element of the matrix $A^{'}$ can be divided by $2$. The new matrix is of the form

$$A^{''}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&0&2\\
0&2&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
By the lemma we have $v_{A^{''}}=\frac{1}{2}v_{A^{'}}=\frac{1}{2}(v_{A}+1)$Verify the value of the game $\Gamma$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2}.$ Indeed, $K(x^{*},{y^{*}})=Ay^{*}=\frac{1}{2}.$ On the other hand, for each strategy $y \in Y,y=(\eta_{1},\eta_{2},\eta_{3})$ we have $K(x^{*},y)=\frac{1}{2}\eta_{1}+\frac{1}{2}\eta_{2}+\frac{1}{2}\eta_{3}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1=\frac{1}{2}$, and for all $x=(\xi_{1},\xi_{2},\xi_{3}),x \in X, K(x,y^{*})=\frac{1}{2}\xi_{1}+\frac{1}{2}\xi_{2}+\frac{1}{2}\xi_{3}.$ Consequently, the above-mentioned strategies $x^{*},y^{*}$ are optimal and $v_{A}=0.$

I don't know why $K(x^{*},y^{*})=Ay^{*}=\frac{1}{2}$, it should be $0$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $K(x^{*},{y^{*}})=x^*A''y^{*}=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: I checked, the PDF is $Ay^{*}$. That's where I got confused of.